# Android ContextMenu for View (Not Activity)

Tags: android, view, contextmenu

I am using the following method to add a `ContextMenu` to a custom view i have built but i want to know how to react to the press of that contextmenu.

This is not an Activity so i cannot do this:

```
  @override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
```

### Here is the code

```
 private View.OnCreateContextMenuListener vC = new View.OnCreateContextMenuListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu arg0, View arg1,
            ContextMenuInfo arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        arg0.add(0, 0, 0, "Call");
        arg0.add(0, 1, 0, "Map");
        arg0.add(0, 2, 0, "Market");


    }


};
```

Update:

Here is a very simplified verion of my class.

```
 public final class NewView extends View {



 public NewView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    cntxt = context;
    this.setLongClickable(true);
    this.setOnLongClickListener(vLong);
    this.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(vC);


 }

private View.OnLongClickListener vLong = new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
        showContextMenu();
             return true;   
    }
 };  
 private View.OnCreateContextMenuListener vC = new View.OnCreateContextMenuListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu arg0, View arg1,
            ContextMenuInfo arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        arg0.add(0, 0, 0, "Call");
        arg0.add(0, 1, 0, "Map");
        arg0.add(0, 2, 0, "Market");


    }

};


  }
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are attempting to embed all of the logic for displaying and handling context menu selections within your view. This does not strike me as good MVC design. To be consistent with the MVC design pattern, you should have an Activity handle the logic of mediating the display of various views and menus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `item.getItemId()` and create `switch` and `cases` based on the number returned by `getItemId()`

Something like this.

```
 @override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

      switch(item.getItemId())
      {
         case 1:
               Log.i("FIRST ITEM: ", "CALL");
               break;
         case 2: 
                Log.i("2nd ITEM: ", "MAP");
                break;
          case 3:
               Log.i("3rd ITEM: ", "Market");
               break;
         default:
      }
}
```

I hope this is what you meant by reacting on menu items selection. :)

Comment: But where is item passed from? There is no @Override to catch the click of the contextmenu?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem)

Comment: Thanks for this but it won't work due to the fact that it is a custom View not a customer Activity i.e. the class extends a View so it doesn't have the ability to override onOptionsItemSelected

Comment: Did you registered for ContexteMenu as @Phil mentioned below?

Comment: I think that Matt's trying to do this without involving an Activity. I don't think this is such a good idea. The Activity should register the customView for context menu and then handle all of the context menu behaviour. None of that behaviour should be coded as part of the customView.

Comment: No, because i want the view independent of any activity but still able  to use ContextMenus of it's own creation. The above updated code works  - shows a contextmenu but i cannot 'item.getItemId()'

Comment: @glorifiedHacker, that is exactly what i want to do. I understand that  it goes against convention but it's part of a project that needs independence from any Activity.

Answer (score 3):

Noone seem to answer exhaustively TS' question (and mine eventually), thus let me post a solution to this. Given the code above you can attach custom MenuItem's click handlers:

```
private View.OnCreateContextMenuListener vC = new View.OnCreateContextMenuListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

        menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Call")
                .setOnMenuItemClickListener(mMenuItemClickListener);
        menu.add(0, 1, 0, "Map")
                .setOnMenuItemClickListener(mMenuItemClickListener);
        menu.add(0, 2, 0, "Market")
                .setOnMenuItemClickListener(mMenuItemClickListener);

    }
};  

private OnMenuItemClickListener mMenuItemClickListener = new OnMenuItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case 0:
                // do "Call"
                return true;

            case 1:
                // do "Map"
                return true;

            case 2:
                // do "Market"
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This does seem to be an odd inconsistency in Android - a View can create a context menu, but the handling of said menu can only happen in completely different code?

I'm also solving this with setOnMenuItemClickListener().  The documentation suggests this is reasonable, but it requires effort to set it up if you are using a MenuInflater.

```
    public void onCreateContextMenu(final ContextMenu menu, final View v,
            final ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        final MenuInflater menuInflater = this.menuInflater;
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.context_date, menu);

        final int length = menu.size();
        for (int index = 0; index < length; index++) {
            final MenuItem menuItem = menu.getItem(index);
            menuItem.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could assign a variable to your `View` from your activity after you inflate the main layout (in `onCreate).

```
myView = (View) findViewById(R.id.my_view);
```

Next, do `registerForContextMenu(myView);`

Finally, you can override `onCreateContextMenu` where you can add what happens when the context menu appears.

Comment: This would work thanks but what i'm looking for is a way for the View itself to register the click of the ContextMenu not an Activity

Answer (score 0):

**In the view** :
Let your view implements ContextMenuInfo

```
public class MyView extends View implements ContextMenuInfo
```

Then, override getContextMenuInfo to return your view.

```
@Override
protected ContextMenuInfo getContextMenuInfo() {
    return  this ;
}
```

**In you activity** :
Register your view for ContextMenu.

```
registerForContextMenu(myView);
```

Then access the view in your activity onContextItemSelected.

```
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        ...
        case R.id.action_ctx_wordview_read_tts:
             MyView myView = (MyView) item.getMenuInfo();
        ...
    }
}
```

**Note** :
When I add an onClickListener to the MyView, the contextMenu stoped working. I had to add the following code to solve the problem.

```
  tvWord.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            return false;
        }
    });
```